# How to detect a DDL statement in a script and exit

Tags: linux, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, ksh

When running a script via SQLPLUS from within a KSH against an Oracle 11.2.0.4 or above database on Linux, is it possible to detect a DDL statement, exit and rollback all previous non DDL statements? So it would be something like this but enhanced to stop on the first DDL.

```
    WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
    @script.sql
```

Is there some way to set exception handling in PLSQL to immediately exit before the first DDL statement can be executed?

Comment: I don't think SQLPlus has any such feature.  Why do you want to club DDL statements and DML statements?

Comment: It would be a bad practice even if you could and not recommended. DDLs and Dmls  should be included in a separate file during deployment . Do not expect Oracle to take care of your bad coding discipline.

Comment: To use PL/SQL exception handling you would first have to code dynamic SQL with `execute immediate` or similar, so it might be a bit odd to also prevent those sections being run. If you wanted to make it conditional, you could write an `exec_ddl` procedure and have that check something before execution. This is all a long way from detecting DDL statements in a SQL\*Plus script though.

Comment: Even if you could stop this, anyone with access to th escript and database login could still "cat" the script and copy/paste DDL, ensuring any WHENEVER directives are relaxed. This only way to guarantee this is to have something within the database to control this.Maybe GRANT via a ROLE that allows DDL, subject to additional authentication, or in the trigger suggested by @wolφi answer below have some sort of hashed password to allow the statements to run, and then figure out how to securely pass this password in from the KSH script.

Comment: I need to be able to rollback the DML changes in the script but if there's a DDL in there rollback won't be possible. DDLs should not be in there but I need to ensure this. One rogue DDL statement and it ruins the rollback automation. I guess I could also just scan the script before hand but I was looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot think of an easy way to do this in SQL*Plus, and this is probably the biggest reason why we always have two accounts at work: One schema user who owns the tables and does all the DDL, and on application user, who has full read and write privs on the tables. The script is run by the application user and cannot execute any DDL at all.

If you insists, though, you could create a DDL trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_ddl_watchdog 
  BEFORE DDL ON SCHEMA
DECLARE
  l_program v$session.program%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT program
    INTO l_program
    FROM v$session 
   WHERE audsid = sys_context('userenv', 'sessionid'); 
  IF lower(l_program) LIKE 'sqlplus%' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'sqlplus may not do DDL');
  END IF;
END my_ddl_watchdog; 
/
```

which fires as soon as an application called sqlplus tries to do DDL:

```
sqlplus user/pwf@localhost:1521/orcl

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK;       

INSERT INTO bla VALUES (1);
1 row created.

DROP TABLE bla;
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20000: sqlplus may not do DDL
Disconnected from Oracle Database...
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'll try it out now. It's only a safe guard to ensure no DDLs are executed.